# What causes the System.Web.HttpException with error code 0x80070057 on Page.Flush while debugging in VS2005?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, exception

Here is the complete error message:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in
>   user code
>
> Additional information: The remote
>   host closed the connection. The error
>   code is 0x80070057.

and the offending code:

```
 char[] buffer = oPage.HTML.HTML.ToCharArray();
 Page.Response.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
 Page.Response.Flush();
 Page.Response.End();
```

The oPage.HTML.HTML is a string in a custom page object used by our app. The exception triggers on Page.Flush() and appears to be benign -- I just hit "continue" and everything goes along fine. This never appears at run time.

I have chased many, many Google hits down many rabbit holes and have found nothing. Visual Studio 2005, Vista Ultimate (IIS7).

Comment: Isn't Flush() unnecessary if it is immediately succeeded by an End()?

Comment: @Chetan: Probably, but this is legacy code on a page that is used in every page of a huge app. I'd like to delete it, but I'm a coward. My current fix is to comment it out on my working copy, and I have no problems locally.

Comment: The same error throws in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been dealing with this same error for a while now, and my understanding is that when Flush is called, there must be a connection on the other end, otherwise, this error is thrown. It's easy to get into a "fire-and-forget" kind of model when writing web pages, but when the client disconnects (in this debugging case, you're the client), there's nowhere to flush *to*.

There are two solutions I've found to this:

1. Wrap Response.Flush and catch the exception.
2. Check Response.IsClientConnected before you call flush.

I'm not 100% sure about the second one...I'm still in the process of checking that one out.

Good luck!

Comment: I suspect #2 is a race condition, since the client may disconnect after you check IsClientConnected.